# Disappearing UIBarButtonItems in iOS 4

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, uibarbuttonitem

I've been developing on an iOS 5 device, and it's been working fine. Now I've been testing it with different versions of the iOS simulator, and in 4.0 I'm getting some strange behaviour with my custom UIBarButtonItems. On the main screen of the app both of the bar buttons show throughout the lifetime of the app. Those two buttons bring up modal view controllers, each with a 'close' button. This is an object description of the 'close' button on one of the modal view controllers (I set a breakpoint in the 'viewWillAppear' method):

```
(gdb) po [[[self navigationItem] rightBarButtonItem] customView]
<UIButton: 0x72766e0; frame = (264 6; 51 31); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7276d70>>
```

Those both show up when the each modal view controller is opened. But then one of the modal view controllers has a button that pushes another view controller on top, and the view controller's base class automatically makes a custom back button and puts it on the leftBarButtonItem of the view. However, this doesn't show up. Here's the object description of the button that doesn't show up (again, in 'viewWillAppear'):

```
(gdb) po [[[self navigationItem] leftBarButtonItem] customView]
<UIButton: 0x766be00; frame = (0 0; 43 31); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x766be90>>
```

...which doesn't look like anything is wrong. I then press where the back button should be, and the view controller pops off, revealing the first modal view controller, but with no 'close' button. Again, I broke in viewWillAppear and this is what I got:

```
(gdb) po [[[self navigationItem] rightBarButtonItem] customView]
<UIButton: 0x72766e0; frame = (264 6; 51 31); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7276d70>>
```

This is strange, since I don't set the alpha value of  a UIBarButtonItem anywhere in my own code. Also, it works fine on  iOS 5. The way I implement the custom UIBarButtonItems is using some static methods I put in a category called UIBarButtonItem+Utils.h that returns UIBarButtonItems initialised with a custom UIButton as the custom view. If you need me to post the code for that method I can, but the main point is that it doesn't ever change the button's alpha value. Has anyone else experienced anything like this?

Comment: Could it be that 'internal' setHidden works with changing alpha. If you're curious you could sublass UIBarButtonItem, override setHidden with NSLogging it's alpha before and after calling [super setHidden:...]. This way you'd also know exactly when the sistem hides this button.

Comment: Has anyone found solution for this? I've been struggling with this for few days and I can't find any solution for this.